# Why are the changes made using [setObject] in the array not reflected when the program leaves the scope of for loop?

Tags: ios, objective-c

This is my app that tries to bring flickr photos details as json and load them in NSDictionary. I do want to categorize or sort the data using country as section or key and then have its value as a array of NSDictionary which will contain place_id, city and place name. I try to do that inside a for loop and according to me it should work, but when i run and see the NSLog i get all the values of same type. I checked couple of times and found out the value are the last item to get inserted into customSortedPlaces.

```
-(IBAction)prepareTopPlacesFromFlickr{
NSLog(@"Refreshing");

[self.refreshControl beginRefreshing];

NSURL *topPlaces= [FlickrFetcher URLforTopPlaces];

//download the json and put it in dictionary
dispatch_queue_t fetchQueue=dispatch_queue_create("FlickrFetch", NULL);

dispatch_async(fetchQueue, ^(){
    NSData *topPlacesData= [NSData dataWithContentsOfURL:topPlaces];

    [self getOrderedDictionaryFrom:topPlacesData];
    [self.refreshControl endRefreshing];
    [self.tableView reloadData];

});
}
```

This method calls this one now, which does the actual sorting thing.

```
-(NSDictionary *) getOrderedDictionaryFrom:(NSData *) topPlacesData{

NSMutableDictionary *topPlacesDictionary=[NSJSONSerialization JSONObjectWithData:topPlacesData options:0 error:NULL];

if(topPlacesDictionary==nil){
    return nil;
}


//sort descriptor
NSSortDescriptor *sortCountry =[NSSortDescriptor sortDescriptorWithKey:@"place_url" ascending:YES];

//get the places array
NSArray *places=[[topPlacesDictionary valueForKeyPath:FLICKR_RESULTS_PLACES] sortedArrayUsingDescriptors:@[sortCountry]];

//    NSLog(@"placesd , %@", places);

NSMutableArray *customSortedPlaces=[[NSMutableArray alloc] init];

NSMutableArray *countryArray=[[NSMutableArray alloc] init];

NSMutableArray *oneCountryPlaceHolder=[[NSMutableArray alloc] init];


//this iteration does check the values, take the needed parts and fix them to the mutable dictionary where keys will  be country name and values array of dictionary containing city, place_id, and city_name

for (NSDictionary *dict in places) {
    NSArray *componentPlace=[[dict objectForKey:@"place_url"] componentsSeparatedByString:@"/"];
    NSString *country=componentPlace[1];// the 0th one is empty string
    NSString *placeWoe= [dict objectForKey:@"woe_name"];

    NSString *placeWithoutCountry; //sometimes we dont have city, street and country so
    if ([componentPlace count]>=4) {
        placeWithoutCountry=[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@ ,%@", componentPlace[2],componentPlace[3]];
    }else{
        placeWithoutCountry=componentPlace[2];
    }

    NSString *placeId=[dict objectForKey:@"place_id"];


    //temp container to contain one place at a time
    NSMutableArray *onePlace=[[NSMutableArray alloc] init];

    if ([countryArray containsObject:country]) {

        //this country is already inserted in one timer unique conuntry array
        //we need to get hold of the dictionary by storing it on a temp array

        //[onePlace removeAllObjects];    //being safe


        [onePlace addObject:placeId];
        [onePlace addObject:placeWithoutCountry ];
        [onePlace addObject:placeWoe];

        //add it to the array
        [oneCountryPlaceHolder addObject:onePlace];


    }else{

        //doesnot contains
        //this is probably the first time if so check the tmep array or county before
        //if this is the second or other times, we add country and add the pending dictionaries of places to the country keyed array

        [countryArray addObject:country];

        //add the previous list
        //insert the placeHolder if not empty into the main array
        if([oneCountryPlaceHolder count]>0){
            [customSortedPlaces addObject:oneCountryPlaceHolder];
                NSLog(@"count %i, %i,%i",[customSortedPlaces count], [oneCountryPlaceHolder count], [countryArray count]);

            NSLog(@"custom sorted array %@",customSortedPlaces);
        }

        //clear the country Place holder
        [oneCountryPlaceHolder removeAllObjects];


        //insert here
        [onePlace removeAllObjects];    //being safe

        [onePlace addObject:placeId];
        [onePlace addObject:placeWithoutCountry ];
        [onePlace addObject:placeWoe];

        //add it to the array
        [oneCountryPlaceHolder addObject:onePlace];

    }

    //NSLog(@"on country place holder%@", customSortedPlaces);


}

//add the last one, basically this gets skipped off


    NSLog(@"hey %@",customSortedPlaces);
return self.customSortedPlaces;

   }
```

So the question is, why is the changes made using [setObject] in the array not reflected when the program leaves the scope of for loop?

Comment: It is really unclear what this code is trying to achieve, but I can see a couple of  issues. 1. You allocate oneCountryPlaceholder outside the loop, which means you are storing a reference same array in `customSortedPlaces` multiple times, so when you change it (remove objects) it affects every entry. 2. You return `self.customsortedplaces`, not the local variable `customSortedPlaces`

Comment: Your code really makes no sense.  Keep in mind that when you add the pointer of an object to an array you are adding the *pointer*, not the object itself.  No copy of the object occurs, so if you later, say, clear that object, the version you placed in the array will be cleared.